# PersonalName on InternetAddress not working with GmailAPI

Tags: java, email, gmail-api

I am using Java Gmail API for sending emails and I am trying to set the personal name displayed on the from field on the gmail client. I found documentation about this can be set with the constructor for the InternetAddress class, but when the email is sent trough Gmail API, it seems it is ignored.

My goal is to be able to display on the from field different names but always using the same email address on different emails.
By Example:

One email displaying:
User1 Lastname `<`main@email.com`>`

Other email displaying:
User2 Lastname2 `<`main@email.com`>`

Other email displaying:
User3 Lastname3 `<`main@email.com`>`

.....

Here is the code:

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
InternetAddress fromEmailAddress = new InternetAddress("main@email.com", "User3 Lastname3");
mimeMessage.setFrom(fromEmailAddress);
.....
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mimeMessage.writeTo(buffer);
byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes);
Message message = new Message();
message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
gmailService.users().messages().send("main@email.com", message).execute();
```

Comment: Do you mean to say there's only one email showing everytime?

Comment: Exactly same email displayed always but, customizing the User Name displayed next to the email. I have seen another apps doing it, so I wonder if it is possible. JIRA is one example of those applications, you receive an email always from the same email address but, it displays the name of the person who made the change on the ticket.